# AWS Cognito for Basic Authentication

Tags: rest, api, amazon-web-services, basic-authentication, amazon-cognito

Will I be able to use AWS Cognito to expose my REST API's using basic authentication.

Basically if my client hits my REST endpoint in the browser, it should prompt for username and password. Further, my API should take the username and password, pass it on to cognito, gets it validated.

Will this flow work out ?Does Cognito expose any API's for basic authentication ? Which I can call from my backend to validate my clients username and password.

Regards
Guru

Answer (score 1):

That should work. Cognito provides low level clients for various languages such as Java, Javascript, C++. Calling Cognito from the backend should be feasible using those clients and it looks like you can use the ADMIN_NO_SRP_AUTH authentication flow for username/password validation.

In Cognito, we expose 2 APIs: initiateAuth or adminInitiateAuth and respondToAuthChallenge or adminRespondToAuthChallenge that can be used to pass parameters to initiate authentication and respond with a password.

Comment: Surely it doesn't make sense that Cognito would allow the application to collect user credentials in clear text and pass them in to the service for the purpose of authenticating a user.  That would amount to "free password giveaway day," would it not?  Also, am I taking the following out of context? ["The ADMIN_NO_SRP_AUTH AuthFlow is not accepted for the InitiateAuth and RespondToAuthChallenge APIs."](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/amazon-cognito-user-pools-authentication-flow.html)  Can you clarify?

Comment: Cognito exposes two types of APIs initiateAuth and respondToAuthChallenge are unauthenticated APIs, that you can freely call without AWS credentials. These APIs have a USER_SRP_AUTH flow that sends a password claim. Cognito provides client-side SDKs for Android, iOS, and Javascript for doing SRP BigInteger math. Server-side, Cognito provides adminInitiateAuth and adminRespondToAuthChallenge that are authenticated APIs, they require AWS credentials. In the doc you linked: "for use on secure backend servers if you want to avoid the SRP calculations" referring to ADMIN_NO_SRP_AUTH and admin APIs.